# How to make a pipe-divided tuple?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'm trying to write a macro, `\tup` that will effectively expand this:

```
\tup{a | b | ... | z}
```

to this:

```
\left\langle a ~\middle|~ b ~\middle|~ ... ~\middle|~ z \right\rangle
```

I tried the following, but it only puts down the first separator and then stops.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\newcommand{\brak}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tup}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
    \@tempswafalse%
    \def\@sep{~\middle|~}%
    \edef\@tempa{#1|}%
    \expandafter\brak\expandafter{\expandafter\@tuploop\@tempa\relax}%
    \endgroup%
}
\def\@tuploop#1|#2\relax{%
      \if@tempswa\@sep\else\@tempswatrue\fi{#1}
      \begingroup
      \ifx\relax#2\relax
         \renewcommand{\next}{\endgroup}%
      \else
         \renewcommand{\next}{\endgroup\@tuploop#2\relax}%
      \fi
      \next
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\tup{a|b|c}$
\end{document}
```

[image: bad output -- only one pipe character]

However, if I change the definition of `\@sep` to `\def\@sep{~|~}` then it "works" and puts the pipe characters in between

[image: ok output -- both pipe characters, but no height adjustment]

I believe `\middle` might be expanding too early, but I'm not sure what to do. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you need a loop:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\|
\lowercase{\endgroup
\def\tup#1{{\def~{\;\middle\vert\;}\mathcode`\|="8000\left\langle#1\right\rangle}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\tup{a | b | c | z} + \tup{a |\frac{A}{B} | c | z}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how this works a little bit? It seems very cool, but I don't know how I would have ever come up with it.

Comment: @AlexReinking it just gives `|` an active definition that expands to `\;\middle\vert\;` so you don't need any looping. The definition uses mathcode `"8000` (math active) so it is only locally special within that argument and other uses of `|` not inside the argument are not affected.

Answer (score 12):

As a general rule, I recommend to avoid `\left` and `\right` whenever possible.

Here's an implementation with a syntax similar to commands defined with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`.

The unadorned command uses normal size; in the optional argument `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg` can appear. The `*` means using automatic sizing.

Spaces in the mandatory argument are ignored, so `\tup{a|b|c}` is the same as `\tup{a | b | c}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tup}{som}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_open_tl { \left\langle }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_middle_tl { \;\middle|\; }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_close_tl { \right\rangle }
   }
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {
      \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_open_tl { \langle }
      \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_middle_tl { \mathrel{|} }
      \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_close_tl { \rangle }
     }
     {
      \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_open_tl { \mathopen{#2\langle} }
      \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_middle_tl { \mathrel{#2|} }
      \tl_set:Nn \l__reinking_tup_close_tl { \mathclose{#2\rangle} }
     }
   }
  \__reinking_tup:n { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__reinking_tup_open_tl
\tl_new:N \l__reinking_tup_middle_tl
\tl_new:N \l__reinking_tup_close_tl
\seq_new:N \l__reinking_tup_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__reinking_tup:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__reinking_tup_items_seq { | } { #1 }
  \l__reinking_tup_open_tl
  \seq_use:NV \l__reinking_tup_items_seq \l__reinking_tup_middle_tl
  \l__reinking_tup_close_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\tup{a|b|\dots|z}$
\quad
$\tup[\big]{a|b|\dots|z}$
\quad
$\tup[\Big]{a|b|\dots|z}$
\quad
$\tup*{\dfrac{a}{2}|b|\dots|z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A package-free version, which indiscriminately uses `\left`, `\middle` and `\right`. The items are absorbed one at a time and appended to a list, then the list is executed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tup}[1]{%
  \def\@tup@list{}%
  \@tup#1|\@tup|
}
\def\@tup#1|{%
  \ifx\@tup#1\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\left\langle\@tup@list\right\rangle}%
  {\ifx\@tup@list\@empty\@tup@append{#1}\else\@tup@append{\;\middle|\;#1}\fi\@tup}%
}
\def\@tup@append#1{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tup@list\expandafter{\@tup@list#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\tup{a}$

$\tup{a|b|\dots|z}$

\end{document}
```

This way there's no problem with groups implicitly formed by `\left`, `\middle` and `\right`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the publishing system I'm submitting to does not have xparse whitelisted.

Comment: @AlexReinking Too bad. Do you *really* need `\left`, `\middle` and `\right`?

Comment: @AlexReinking I added a package-free version.

Comment: Perhaps `\ifx\@tup#1` in case one uses `\tup{aa}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You're right. I opted for `\ifx\@tup#1\relax` which also copes with an empty argument.

Comment: I had to step away for a meeting, sorry. I suppose I don't strictly need left/middle/right, but I do need that effect. The [TAPS ACM whitelist](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/whitelist-of-latex-packages) is available here. It's a bit suffocating.

Comment: How does that `\ifx` comparison work? Why is `\@tup` its first argument?

Comment: @AlexReinking The value of `#1` is everything up to the first `|` token. Now `\ifx\@tup#1\relax` compares `\@tup` with the first token in `#1` (or to `\relax`). Only when we're at the end the token list (we added `\@tup|` at the end) returns true; in this case we deliver what we had earlier surrounded by `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle`. Otherwise we append `\;\middle|\;#1` (the actual tokens represented by `#1`) unless the list is still empty, when we only append `#1`.

Comment: Aha, I see how that works with the `\@tup#1|\@tup|` line, now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your command was *almost* working. If you put more items in `\tup`, like `$\tup{a|b|c|d|e|f}$` you'd see this:

> [image]

it's not the first item which is left out, rather they are grouped in pairs. Your command starts with a `\left\langle`, which starts a "math left group" and with the `\@tempswa` switch set to false. In the first iteration of `\@tuploop` you do `\if@tempswa\@sep\else\@tempswatrue\fi` which expands to `\@tempswatrue`, meaning that no `\@sep` is inserted now, and `\@tempswa` is now true. The command then inserts the first item (`a`) and proceeds to the next iteration.

On the second iteration, `\@tempswa` is true and `\if@tempswa\@sep\else\@tempswatrue\fi` expands to `\@sep`, which inserts a `\middle|` (the separator after `a`). The `\middle` primitive will end the "math left group" started by `\left\langle` and will start another "math left group". However, when the first group ended, your `\@tempswa` switch was restored to its value outside the current group, which is false! And now the command inserts `b` and goes to the third iteration, but now with `\@tempswa` set to false once again.

So your command was actually inserting `<token>|<token>` and then `<token>|<token>`, and so on, due to the end of group triggered by `\middle`. You could circumvent this with some `\aftergroup` magic, or simply making a gloabl assignment to the switch:

```
\if@tempswa\@sep\else\global\@tempswatrue\fi
```

However, as egreg said in the comment, `\@tempswa` is supposed to be set locally only, so it would be better if you created a `\newif\ifg@insertsep` and then always used `\global\g@insertseptrue` and `\global\g@insertsepfalse`.

And since meanwhile egreg posted a much more elaborate `expl3` answer than the one-liner I would post, I'll stop here ;-)

Comment: `\if@tempswa` should only be set locally. A different conditional to be always used globally would be preferable.

Comment: @egreg How would I know that without `\g_...`? ;-) Thanks for pointing it out, I added a note in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be space for one more answer, in which one could mention that all this seems to have been done some long time ago.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\[
\Braket{a | b | c | z} + \Braket{a |\frac{A}{B} | c | z}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Back then they also needed no loop. ;-)

Comment: Well, this is definitely how I will do this whenever I don't have a strict whitelist of packages to adhere to.